# How to check for duplicate value in database when I save data

Tags: vb.net

How can I check for duplicate values in a database when I save data.

```
Private Sub ButtonSave_Click() Handles ButtonSave.Click

    If IsDataComplete() = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sql = "INSERT INTO Categories(CategoryName) VALUES(@name)"

    command.Parameters.Clear()
    command.CommandText = sql
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", TextName.Text)

    Dim result As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If result = -1 Then

        MessageBox.Show("เกิดข้อผิดพลาดไม่สามารถเพิ่มข้อมูลได้") 'error
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("บันทึกข้อมูล") 'data saved
        ButtonAdd.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: We see this question asked a lot and it really shouldn't be at all. You want to know whether data exists in a database that satisfies specific criteria?  How do you usually get data that satisfies specific criteria?  With a query.

Comment: It would help to know what database you are using. Add the information to your question by clicking the edit link and adding a tag or text.

Comment: It looks like you are scoping your Command object (and Connection object) outside of the Sub above. You shouldn't, and instead declare them at the point of use (make sure to use the `Using` keyword to declare them. Otherwise you're asking for all sorts of hard-to-find bugs and issues by reusing them over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ([Column]=@Value)
```

Or you could also do

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ([Column]) VALUES (@Value) ON CONFLICT ([Column]) DO UPDATE SET [Column]=@Value
```

Which will try to insert, and if there is an error it will update instead.

Comment: What database does this work for? A quick try on Sql Server seems to fail.

Comment: @Mary Looks like PostgreSQL. [Insert documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Mary Well I used this specific thing in SQLite, but should be fairly standard sql no? I used similar to access Ms access in winforms (that oledb though)

Comment: I would think you would want `DO NOTHING` in the OP's scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local so you can control when they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will handle this chore even if there is an error.

Very glad to see the use of Parameters but use the `.Add` method. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html
The `.AddWithValue` forces .net to infer the type you are passing in and since all strings in .net are unicode the parameter is sent as an nvarchar.

The `If Not Exists` in the sql statement is part of Transact Sql used by Sql Server but something similar should be available in other databases.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("If Not Exists(select 1 from Categories where CategoryName = @Name) Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (@Name);", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextName.Text
            cn.Open()
            retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
    End Using
    If retVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful Insert")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Item is duplicate")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Error Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. on `cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")`

Comment: @TaritManCh replace "Your connection string" with Your connection string.

Comment: @preciousbetine how to please ?

Comment: Do you have your connection string? Just copy and paste or type it in your code where "Your connection string" appears. Delete "Your connection string".